# Is the unitary group connected in infinite dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbertspace and $U(H)$ the group of unitaries endowed with the norm topology.

> **Is $U(H)$ connected?**

The following is a generalisation of the proof in the finite-dimensional case but will not work for an arbitrary unitary:

> If we consider a unitary $u$, then $\Bbb1, u, u^*$ generate an abelian $C^*$-algebra isomorphic to $C(\sigma(u))$, here $\sigma(u)\subset S^1$ and $u$ corresponds to the function $\sigma(u)\to\Bbb C$, $z\mapsto z$. In the event that $\sigma(u)\neq S^1$ one can define a homotopy on $S^1$ that deforms $\sigma(u)$ to a point. This homotopy will correspond to a path that brings $u$ to $\Bbb1$ via unitaries in $C(\sigma(u))$ and thus in $U(H)$.

For $\sigma(u)=S^1$ such a homotopy is impossible, and $u$ is not connected to $\Bbb1$ in $C(\sigma(u))$. However if there exists a path in $U(H)$ connecting $u$ to a unitary with spectrum smaller than $S^1$, the above will give the result.

Another approach I had thought about was looking at the Cayley transform, however this does not have image all of $U(H)$. Finding a logarithm (ie a self-adjoint $A$ with $\exp(A)=u$) would give a path from $u$ to $\Bbb 1$ via $\exp(tA)$, but this path is only strongly continuous and not norm continuous.

Comment: Just as a side remark, the space $U(H)$ is even contractible by Kuiper's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B(H)$ is a von Neumann algebra and you are allowed to use Borel functional calculus, so every unitary is connected to the identity.

Comment: I see, we may extend the algebra in my post to $L^\infty(\sigma(u))$ and remain a subalgebra of $B(H)$. Here any $S^1$ valued function may deformed continuously to the identity.

Comment: Maybe not any but the function $e^{it} \mapsto t$ is now Borel and hence applied to your unitary $u$ defines a logarithm, say $h$, of it. Then $t \mapsto e^{ith}$ deforms $u$ into $1$.

Comment: Let $A_1, A_2$ and be a decomposition of $S^1$ into an open and a closed "interval". Then any function $f= f_1+f_2$ where $f_1$ is zero on $A_i$. Now you can homotopy $A_i$ to points and then $f_i\circ h_{i,t}$ is a homotopy to a constant map that remains $S^1$-valued and in $L^\infty$. $f_1\circ h_{1,t} + f_2\circ h_{2,t}$ then deforms $f$ within $L^\infty$ to a function taking on at most two values, which can then be further deformed to the constant map.

Comment: Note also that the map $t\mapsto e^{ith}$ is not necessarily _norm continuous_. In general it is only strongly continuous.

Comment: The function $t \mapsto e^{ith}$ is surely norm continuous.

Comment: The generator $h$ of a semi-group can be unbounded, then you don't have norm-continuity. I was thinking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups . Although I see that you could define a bounded generator since you are only interested in hitting a specific unitary.

Comment: Okay, I already assumed that $h \in B(H)$, which is possible.